# Cygwin dumper for Windows process?

Tags: cygwin, coredump, procdump

Cygwin includes a program `dumper.exe`

> The dumper utility can be used to create a core dump of running Windows
>   process.

```
Usage: dumper [OPTION] FILENAME WIN32PID

Dump core from WIN32PID to FILENAME.core
```

However it seems to only work with Cygwin processes

```
$ ps -Ws | grep calc
   3880 ?        20:22:02 C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe

$ dumper calc-dump 3880
Cannot attach to process #3880, error 50
```

I have been using [**ProcDump**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) for some time now, but I would like to move to a program that is included in Cygwin packages.

Comment: Steven, how did you have ProcDump configured to work with Cygwin?  I can't get dumps for any Windows process that is a child process of CygWin.

Comment: @w25r I believe I was only using it on native Windows processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `dumper.exe` **will** work with a Windows process, but only **32-bit processes**.

```
$ C:/Windows/SysWOW64/calc.exe &
[1] 3660

$ dumper calc 3660 &
[2] 3500

$ ls -l
total 18688
-rw-r--r--+ 1 Steven None 19071028 Jun  7 20:38 calc.core
```